Building Python/Kivy/Pickle executable with PyInstaller
I'm trying to build a standalone executable from a program written in Python and Kivy using PyInstaller. The program saves some values into a Pickle file, but when I add that file to PyInstaller with --add-data="path/to/file.pkl:path/into/package/" and execute it, the program return me an error which says that file doesn't exist.
I tried to add pickle to PyInstaller with --add-binaries, but nothing changed.
I used --add-data also for a couple of json files, and works with any error.
How could I fix it?
Here's my build script:
python -m PyInstaller --onefile --noconsole --windowed \
--icon="../TOOL/utils/style/EC_APP_ICON.ico" \
--name="EC App" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/fonts/Long Today.ttf:utils/fonts/" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/fonts/HeyFun.ttf:utils/fonts" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/fonts/Copyduck.ttf:utils/fonts" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/style/gui.kv:utils/style/" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/style/logo.png:utils/style/" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/style/ita.png:utils/style" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/style/eng.png:utils/style" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/style/reset.png:utils/style/" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/style/download.png:utils/style" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/style/EC_APP_ICON.ico:utils/style" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/lang/ita-eng.json:utils/lang/" \
--add-data="../TOOL/utils/lang/eng-ita.json:utils/lang/" \
--add-binary="../TOOL/utils/save/restore.pkl:utils/save/" \
--add-binary="../TOOL/utils/save/dump.pkl:utils/save/" ..\TOOL\tool.py



always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

maybe take path/to/file.pkl form error message and check if you can access it from folder where you run PyInstaller. You may at least use dir path/to/file.pkl or ls path/to/file.pkl (on Linux) to test it. Maybe you have some typo in name, or maybe it needs /full/path/to/file.pkl instead of relative path.
